# ssh server alternative for remote terminal e.g like putty work

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, remote-connection

As per my knowledge, [putty](http://www.putty.org/) is the best solution for the remote terminal but we need run the **ssh server** on Linux.

In my case, I want to take Linux remote terminal on Windows machine but do not want to install the ssh server on Linux.

I am searching on google but not find any method for remote terminal without ssh server.

So my Question is there any way to take Linux terminal on windows without **ssh server.**

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a remote host? If so, is this remote machine using Linux or Windows?

Comment: @rovr138 yes I am trying to connect to a remote host.It is Linux but for this, i need to run ssh server.on Linux side tiny memory and processor so it starts hanging.so I do not want start ssh server on Linux.

Comment: Hints: "bind shell", "reverse shell", "`telnet`". Make sure you understand security issues.

Comment: Multi-posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413088/ .

Answer (score 1):

Your most lightweight option will be binding your shell to a port using something like Netcat. Something to remember is that OpenSSH does more. It helps authenticate and secure the connection. Netcat does none of this.

Anyway, on your remote Linux machine run,

```
netcat -lp 9999 -e /bin/sh
```

and on your Windows machine run something like,

```
netcat example.com 9999
```

Where `example.com` is the domain or IP of the Linux machine.
This basically exposes `/bin/sh` on port `9999`. Your second command connects to it.

Disconnecting from the Windows machine should close the previous connection. If you want it stay alive, run something like,

```
while TRUE; do netcat -lp 9999 -e /bin/sh; done
```

Which will keep restart this after it closes.

- This has NO authentication. ANYONE can connect to this.
- ALL data is sent as cleartext including any password you send.

Be careful.